# populating a spinner manually in.java file

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner and I am trying to populate it manually in the java file, but every time I run the app I get a force close message.

Eclipse does not display any errors.

Here is my code:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
            Spinner testlist = new Spinner(getApplicationContext()); 
            ArrayAdapter <String> adapter =
                      new ArrayAdapter <String> (BlehActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items );
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    testlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            ll1.addView(testlist);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Activitys context to create the Spinner, as you are attaching Spinner to the Activity Layout.

```
Spinner testlist = new Spinner(Activity_Name.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `getApplicationContext()` to initialize your spinner view. Instead you should use Activity's context. for e.g.:

```
Spinner testlist = new Spinner(BlehActivity.this);
```